Delegate of my function has a null target
I am using ROS or ZMQ in Unity to communicate with my device, and I want my code to be adaptable to both methods without having to refactor all my code. Then I created an interface class that make the link between my main code, and the communication library. However, when subscribing to a ROS topic, I need to use a callback function to get the data. But my callback is never called, and when I check the target of the Delegate, it is null, even if I specified this at the creation.
Here is the main class, that defines the subscriber and asks for the creation to the interface. I put with comments the results of each debug command. Since the type for the messages is different between ROS and ZMQ, I am using an alias, defined like this for ROS: public override Type TypeFloatArrayAlias { get; } = typeof(Float32MultiArrayMsg);.
// ... (class RobotCommand)

    try
    {
        var defineSubscriberMethod = m_interface.GetType().GetMethod("DefineSubscriber");
        var genericMethod = defineSubscriberMethod.MakeGenericMethod(m_interface.TypeFloatArrayAlias);
        var delegateType = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(m_interface.TypeFloatArrayAlias);
        
        var methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (methodInfo == null)
            throw new Exception("Method 'UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback' not found.");

        Debug.Log($"Method Info: {methodInfo.Name} Target: {this.GetType().Name}");
        // Method Info: UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback Target: RobotCommand
        Delegate callbackDelegate = Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateType, this, methodInfo);
        Debug.Log($"Delegate Target: {callbackDelegate.Target}, Method: {callbackDelegate.Method}");
        // Delegate Target: null, Method: Void UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback(RosMessageTypes.Std.Float32MultiArrayMsg)

        genericMethod.Invoke(m_interface, new object[]
        {
            Const.ROS_NAMESPACE + "robot_joint_values",
            callbackDelegate
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Error invoking DefineSubscriber: {e.Message}");
    }
}

public void UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback(Float32MultiArrayMsg msg)
{
    Debug.Log("called");
    StartCoroutine(m_controller.MoveRobot_Coroutine(m_interface.ToFloatArray(msg)));
}

Here is the DefineSubscriber<T> method of the interface:
public override void DefineSubscriber<T>(string topic, Action<T> callback)
{
    try
    {
        Debug.Log($"Delegate Callback: Target={callback.Target}, Method={callback.Method}");
        // Delegate Callback: Target=null, Method=Void UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback(RosMessageTypes.Std.Float32MultiArrayMsg)

        Type msgType = typeof(T);
        // _node is the ROS object (ROSConnection.GetOrCreateInstance())
        var subscribeMethod = _node.GetType().GetMethod("Subscribe").MakeGenericMethod(msgType);
        subscribeMethod.Invoke(_node, new object[] { topic, callback });
        
        _subscriberList[topic] = (x => callback((T)x), msgType);
        Debug.Log($"Subscriber created for topic: {topic} with message type: {msgType.Name}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Error while defining subscriber for topic {topic}: {e.Message}");
    }
}

I don't understand why the target of my callback is null, then I guess that's why it is never called because it is not linked to the object.
FYI, here is a working creation of a subscriber:
void Start()
{
    ROSConnection.GetOrCreateInstance().Subscribe<Float32MultiArrayMsg>(m_topicName, UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

void UpdateVirtualRobotJointsCallback(Float32MultiArrayMsg msg)
{
    Debug.Log("called");
    StartCoroutine(xarmController.MoveRobot_Coroutine(new List<float>(msg.data)));
}


Is callbackDelegate.Target == null?

What is that RobotCommand class exactly? Is is a MonoBehaviour? If so, are you sure you actually use a proper instance of that class? So that it is an actual component on a gameobject? You can not create MonoBehaviour derived classes with new. If you do the instance would becomes a "fake null object". Besides that it's hard to tell from the information given.

@shingo Yes
@Bunny83 RobotCommand is a child class of MonoBehaviour, but I created it with the new keyword in another class (also MonoBehaviour) that is linked to a proper object. I didn't know that. How can I create my RobotCommand to avoid that, or should I necessarily link it to a component?

You mentioned target in Debug.Log several times. What is null, exactly? Could you edit your source code and point out exact object that causes the problem?
